# How to create two borders - Pure CSS

Tags: css, styles, border

I am simply trying to achieve the same effect as in the image below*. I want the Header to have two borders, one is lighter than the other to give it an embossed feel.

Before I asked this question on here, I have already done some research and tried ideas inspired from websites like: CSS-Tricks, Daverupert ect... But they are adding Outlines - and after trying that it didn't really work on modern browsers so how about the old ones!

*Since I am now allowed to post an image at this time, please refer to this link for an image: http://postimg.org/image/4b6ne0qod/

Please take a look at my website here: leo.meeped.co.uk Look at the header - you will also notice that it has a shadow after the think border that makes it look like it's edge has been folded.

**Update:** I very like this folding effect, however it makes the header fade out a bit / not stand-out when you scroll down to a white or gray page - as it seem like the shadow blend with the page since they are a very relative colours. So the idea was to add anther border just under the current border to make to emphasise it's edge.

**Hope my question is clear, I am looking for your opinions and help.**

In case you want the HTML and CSS of my site then here it is:

```
     <!--Header--><header>
        <div id="headerWrapper">
            <div id="headerContent">

                <div id="headerLogo">
                    <a href="index.html"><img alt="loai design studio logo" src="assets/elements/logo.png"/></a>
                </div>

                <nav><ul id="mainMenu" class="snapjs-expand-left">
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About Me</a></li>
                    <li><a class="active" href="contact.html">Contact Me</a></li>
                    <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                </ul></nav>

            </div>
        </div>
    </header>




    /*HEADER////////////////////////////////////////////*/  
    /*Header Wrapper*/#headerWrapper {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 border-bottom: 5px solid #E8E8E8;

 width: 100%;
 position: fixed; 
 top: 0; left: 0; 

 z-index: 1000;

 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.20);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.20);
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.20);
         }

      /*Header Content Container*/#headerContent {
   padding: 0 20px;
          }

      /*Header Logo*/
     #headerLogo {
width: 130px;
margin: 19px 0;
float: left;
     }

    /*Main Menu*/
    #mainMenu {
         float: right;
         margin: 17px 0;
    }

#mainMenu li {
    float: left;
}

#mainMenu a {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    margin-left: 3px;

    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
}

#mainMenu a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    background-color: #4E6C98;
}   

#mainMenu a.active {
    color: #4E6C98;
    cursor: default;
}

#mainMenu a.active:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    background: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want two borders without using CSS's outline property, why don't you simply create a border bottom for div#headerWrapper and one for div#headerContent making that of headerWrapper darker:

```
div#headerWrapper
{
  border-bottom: solid 1px #3D9ED5;
}

div#headerContent
{
  border-bottom: solid 1px #81CEFA;
  background-color: #54BEFB;
}
```

If you want the exact appearance of your picture, you can do so by adding the following code (assuming that the part below the border should be empty):

```
header
{
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #FBFBFB;
}
```

If text should be inserted into the lower half of the picture, add it after the outer div (in header) and remove the height from the CSS.

Comment: I thought about that, but the problem was that The HeaderContnet with is only 1030px, while the wrapper is 100%

Comment: Can't you change that width to 1030px while changing margin to auto (I assume that you have wrapper width 100% because of putting your title into the middle)?

Comment: I just recognize, that there is your CSS code in your code snippet. I'm sorry, I forgot that part.

Comment: Which div should get the double border and why don't you want to use outline?

Comment: Please take a look at my website here: leo.meeped.co.uk Look at the header - you will also notice that it has a shadow after the think border that makes it look like it's edge has been folded.

I very like this folding effect, however it makes the header fade out a bit / not stand-out when you scroll down to a white or gray page - as it seem like the shadow blend with the page since they are a very relative colours. So the idea was to add anther border just under the current border to make to emphasise it's edge.

Comment: And the other border must be applied to #headerWrapper which already have the main border. Bare in mind, #headerWrapper have a shadow that I may consider to get rid of - if we can make a border using the shadow property. And I am not using outlines as it does not work properly on Firefox and maybe other browsers - I have red that it can cause lot of trouble.

Comment: You can try to make something like this: `<header><div id = "headerSuperWrapper"><div id = "headerWrapper"><div id = "headerContent">...</div></div></div></header>` and in CSS (I think you can imagine): `#headerSuperWrapper { border-bottom: solid 1px red; }` (red only for example). The HTML looks ugly, I know, but this seems the only possible way to achieve what you want, and yeah, if you find it a bit ugly, I share your opinion but show inside professional web pages like Google mail. This solution won't be that ugly.

Comment: As an addition: I assume that the second border should be below the thick one. If you want that the second one is above, than simply change the border bottom properties of #headerSuperWrapper and #headerWrapper (but I think you can imagine that).

Answer (score 0):

Try using CSS box shadows to create "shadows". For example:

```
#headerWrapper {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,0,0,0.8), 0 2px 0 rgba(0,255,0,0.8);
}
```

Each new shadow should be separated by a comma.

Does this do what you were wanting?

The browser support is pretty good for box shadows now but you might want to keep it in mind. Pretty much everything except IE8 supports it if you use all the vendor prefixes, for more info see: http://caniuse.com/css-boxshadow